# Python/Pandas - How to split data based on the indicated position (row by row)

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe with a 'name' column which displays a name created according to some rules. These rules are in the following columns, where I have the 'separator' (if it's an underscore or any other) and the positions where each information is. For example in the first row I know that the name has an underscore separator and that the first information is the SKU (position 0), the second is the campaign name (position 1) and the third is the campaign objective (position 2).

I'm trying to do a split based on the number each column has, but I'm having trouble doing that.

```
results = pd.DataFrame([{'data': '2022-01-01' , 'canal': 'Facebook/Instagram' , 'campaign_name': 'SKU098_COMMERCIALCAMPAIGN_VIEW' , 'Cost': 1.5 , 'separator': '_' , 'SKU': 0, 'CAMPAIGN': 1, 'GOAL': 2, 'FORMAT': 100},
                        {'data': '2019-01-01' , 'canal': 'Facebook/Instagram' , 'campaign_name': 'NEWYEAR_REACH_SKU4354' , 'Cost': 0.4 , 'separator': '_' , 'SKU': 2, 'CAMPAIGN': 0, 'GOAL': 1, 'FORMAT': 100},
                        {'data': '2022-01-09' , 'canal': 'Facebook/Instagram' , 'campaign_name': 'VIDEO_REACH_SKU4354' , 'Cost': 2.1 , 'separator': '_' , 'SKU': 2, 'CAMPAIGN': 100, 'GOAL': 1, 'FORMAT': 0},
                        {'data': '2022-08-20' , 'canal': 'Facebook/Instagram' , 'campaign_name': 'INTERATIONS/SKU2134/CHRISTMAS' , 'Cost': 1.2 , 'separator': '/' , 'SKU': 1, 'CAMPAIGN': 2, 'GOAL': 0, 'FORMAT': 100}
                       ])
print(results)

        data               canal                   campaign_name  Cost  separator  SKU  CAMPAIGN  GOAL  FORMAT  
0  2022-01-01  Facebook/Instagram  SKU098_COMMERCIALCAMPAIGN_VIEW   1.5          _    0         1     2     100  
1  2019-01-01  Facebook/Instagram           NEWYEAR_REACH_SKU4354   0.4          _    2         0     1     100    
2  2022-01-09  Facebook/Instagram             VIDEO_REACH_SKU4354   2.1          _    2       100     1       0   
3  2022-08-20  Facebook/Instagram   INTERATIONS/SKU2134/CHRISTMAS   1.2          /    1         2     0     100
```

My code is:

```
results['SKU_2'] = results['campaign_name'].str.split(results['separator']).str[results['SKU']]
```

The expected dataframe is:

```
        data               canal                   campaign_name  Cost separator      SKU         CAMPAIGN               GOAL        FORMAT  
0  2022-01-01  Facebook/Instagram  SKU098_COMMERCIALCAMPAIGN_VIEW   1.5          _    SKU098      COMMERCIALCAMPAIGN     VIEW        NaN  
1  2019-01-01  Facebook/Instagram           NEWYEAR_REACH_SKU4354   0.4          _    SKU4354     NEWYEAR                REACH       NaN 
2  2022-01-09  Facebook/Instagram             VIDEO_REACH_SKU4354   2.1          _    SKU4354     NaN                    REACH       VIDEO 
3  2022-08-20  Facebook/Instagram   INTERATIONS/SKU2134/CHRISTMAS   1.2          /    SKU2134     CHRISTMAS              INTERATIONS NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Below code using **itemgetter**

```
from operator import itemgetter 

results.apply(lambda x: ','.join( itemgetter(*[x.SKU, x.CAMPAIGN, x.GOAL])(x['name'].split(x['separator'])) ), axis = 1).str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Updating code as OP's comment below , in case there are many columns with INDEX value. Assumption: Index columns start after NAME & SEPERATOR

```
results.apply(lambda x: ','.join( itemgetter(*x[list(results.columns[2:])])(x['name'].split(x['separator'])) ), axis = 1).str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Updated Code as per OP's comments below

```
def columns_values(col_indices, col_values):
  res = []
  for idx in col_indices:
    if idx < 100:
      res.append(col_values[idx])
    else:
      res.append('nan')
  return res

results[[col+'_2' for col in results.columns[5:]]] = results.apply(lambda x: ','.join( columns_values(x[[col for col in results.columns[5:]]], 
                                                                                                      x['campaign_name'].split(x['separator'])) ), 
                                                                   axis = 1).str.split(',', expand=True)

results.replace('nan', np.nan)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, but unfortunately it's not working... I have several other columns in this table and in addition to that, the SKU, CAMPAIGN and GOAL columns may not have any value (NaN)... where do i add the other columns?

Comment: Check Updated code. Please add example data for NAN cases, what NAME Value will look like & expected output.

Comment: I've updated the data sample and include the columns I have in my dataframe... in addition, I've changed the null values to 100, so I guarantee you won't have any problems and that you won't find any information at position number 100.

Comment: Any specific meaning of 'FORMAT' column?

Comment: is another variable (as well as SKU, CAMPAIGN, GOAL)...

Comment: Check Updated code